# Accessible virtual (on-screen) keyboard on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: keyboard, 17.04, accessibility, onboard

I've just upgraded the Ubuntu in my notebook to the new version, through a dist-upgrade on terminal. In this new version, the native on-screen keyboard is, I guess, the Caribou, which is a "tablet-like" keyboard. However, I need the virtual keyboard for accessibility reasons, and the Caribou is not adequate for me.

I've tried installing the Onboard keyboard, which was the native in former versions, from the app store but it doesn't work well in this version of the OS. So, is there a way to replace the Caribou virtual keyboard with Onboard or other accessibility-friendly on-screen keyboards on Ubuntu 17.04?

Comment: not best bet, you can try `cellwriter` like  `cellwriter --keyboard-only --show-window  --window-y=768 --window-x=512`